# Strange VB casting between inherited types

Tags: vb.net, casting, moq

I have a base class defined as:

```
Public MustInherit Class BaseRepository(Of T As Class)
```

and a class that inherits from this class, defined as:

```
    Public Class CommunicationTypeRepository
        Inherits BaseRepository(Of CommunicationType)
```

For testing purposes I have created a helper method that will use Moq to help fetching some basic data:

```
Public Shared Function GetRepository(Of TEntity As Class, _
                           TRepo As BaseRepository(Of TEntity)) _
                           (ByVal sampleData As IList(Of TEntity)) As TRepo

    Dim repoWithFakeBase = New Mock(Of TRepo)()
    repoWithFakeBase.Setup(Function(x) x.GetAll()).Returns(sampleData.AsQueryable())
    Return repoWithFakeBase.Object
End Function
```

The `GetAll` method is in the `BaseRepository` class.

At runtime I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No coercion operator is defined between types 'DomainModel.Concrete.CommunicationTypeRepository' and 'DomainModel.Abstract.BaseRepository`1[T]'.
```

What's the obvious thing that I'm missing?

Oh and here's the callstack of the error, what supprised me was that the conversion is being done inside the linq namesapce:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : No coercion operator is defined between types 'DomainModel.Concrete.CommunicationTypeRepository' and 'DomainModel.Abstract.BaseRepository`1[T]'.
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetUserDefinedCoercionOrThrow(ExpressionType coercionType, Expression expression, Type convertToType)
at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Convert(Expression expression, Type type)
at DomainTests.Concrete.CommunicationTypeRepositoryTest.GetRepository[TEntity,TRepo](IList`1 sampleData)
at DomainTests.Concrete.CommunicationTypeRepositoryTest.Correct_Item_Found_When_Searched_By_Code()
```

Comment: Have you found anything about this, man? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Yep, it's a fundamental restriction of the .Net framework. If you get Jon Skeets book' C# in depth' he covers it (not a C# or VB specific problem).

Comment: @ilivewithian could you post the solution as an answer to this question?